# MongoDB update object rather than insert a new one

Tags: python, mongodb

Using `collection.insert_one(json_dict)`inserts a new collection

Can I do `collection.insert_one()` on an already existing object so it then updates.

My object will look something like:

```
"_id":  1,
"name": "Bob"
"Age": "57"
```

Then under "Age" I want to add `"Location": "New York'`, how'd I do that using PyMongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to add new field to existing document, you need to update it.
There is a function `collection.update_one(query, new_values)`. First argument is query to match existing document and second argument is update document, which will contain update operation. In your case, it would be `$set`. Read more about `update_one` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/). So, final operation will look like this.

```
collection.update_one({"_id": 1}, {"$set": {"Location": "New York"}})
```

It will find document with `_id` 1 and set `Location` field or update it if already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update` method with `upsert: true` to achieve this.

Normally, `update` changes an existing document. But with `upsert: true` - if no matching document is found for the update, a new document is created.

Docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-upsert